# How to recalculate a matrix to get correct values?

Tags: r, dataframe, precision, calculation

I have similarity matrix in data.frame (54x54), a part below

```
        k2m1    k2m2    k3m1    k3m2    k3m3    k4m1    k4m2    k4m3    k4m4    k5m1    k5m2    k5m3    k5m4    k5m5    k6m1    k6m2
k2m1 1.00000 0.70593 0.98712 0.67291 0.84659 0.83849 0.69555 0.94776 0.29571 0.83640 0.78021 0.78101 0.80930 0.29568 0.90375 0.66605
k2m2 0.70593 1.00000 0.62491 0.99506 0.93949 0.88436 0.97591 0.55784 0.44880 0.88685 0.94409 0.93483 0.35098 0.44874 0.75674 0.96503
k3m1 0.98712 0.62491 1.00000 0.58903 0.77023 0.76720 0.61293 0.97078 0.26117 0.76834 0.70287 0.70255 0.87783 0.26114 0.85845 0.58731
k3m2 0.67291 0.99506 0.58903 1.00000 0.91326 0.87418 0.98249 0.51427 0.44762 0.85752 0.94062 0.93468 0.31851 0.44756 0.71141 0.97317
k3m3 0.84659 0.93949 0.77023 0.91326 1.00000 0.93244 0.91640 0.71039 0.41196 0.96470 0.93509 0.92326 0.48356 0.41191 0.90513 0.88415
k4m1 0.83849 0.88436 0.76720 0.87418 0.93244 1.00000 0.87680 0.65148 0.35668 0.89307 0.95398 0.93431 0.48784 0.35664 0.80183 0.85987
```

when I transform it to distance matrix with:

```
df <- 1 - df
```

I get some of the 1-1 subtractions as '0' but some are '2.2204e-16', see below:

```
         k2m1       k2m2       k3m1      k3m2     k3m3     k4m1     k4m2     k4m3    k4m4     k5m1     k5m2     k5m3    k5m4    k5m5
k2m1 0.000000 2.9407e-01 1.2878e-02 0.3270884 0.153409 0.161507 0.304450 0.052237 0.70429 0.163605 0.219794 0.218985 0.19070 0.70432
k2m2 0.294070 2.2204e-16 3.7509e-01 0.0049388 0.060515 0.115635 0.024087 0.442162 0.55120 0.113154 0.055910 0.065169 0.64902 0.55126
k3m1 0.012878 3.7509e-01 1.1102e-16 0.4109739 0.229773 0.232802 0.387071 0.029223 0.73883 0.231656 0.297130 0.297452 0.12217 0.73886
k3m2 0.327088 4.9388e-03 4.1097e-01 0.0000000 0.086735 0.125816 0.017506 0.485726 0.55238 0.142484 0.059376 0.065321 0.68149 0.55244
k3m3 0.153409 6.0515e-02 2.2977e-01 0.0867352 0.000000 0.067559 0.083599 0.289610 0.58804 0.035305 0.064912 0.076741 0.51644 0.58809
k4m1 0.161507 1.1564e-01 2.3280e-01 0.1258165 0.067559 0.000000 0.123199 0.348521 0.64332 0.106927 0.046022 0.065694 0.51216 0.64336
```

I know it's a really low value but I do not feel it should be like that. How to get the values right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your code

```
df <- `diag<-`(df, 0)
```

or

```
replace(df, df <= sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), 0)
```

Comment: Hi @ThomasIsCoding, I'm not a native programmer neither fluent in R, just a biologist. I figured out the first solution is just replacing values to '0' on diagonal, the second works on all the smallest values wherever they are located in the data frame. The latter works better as there were some similarities with coefficients equal to 1. It doesn't change the tree but makes me feel better :) Thank you very much